# couldn't connect to oracle database connection via Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, configuration-files

Although I can open my connection using **SQL Plus**, I am unable to open that connection using **Oracle SQL Developer**.

Earlier there was no problem. But, a friend of mine wanted to reach my database through another computer. So, he maybe edited some configuration files like:
`listener.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` or `tnsnames.ora`.
But I'm really not sure if this caused the problem.

If the problem is from the previous configuration files then please provide me a link to the files in the default state.

Comment: In SQL Developer, go to Tools => Preferences and locate "Database" and then "Advanced".  There should be two options for "Use Oracle Client" and "Tnsnames Directory" .. indicate what values (if any) you have specified there, as well as what options are available when you click Configure. Might help - only time I've seen something like this is when you have multiple Oracle Home's defined.

Comment: there is only a Tnsnames Directory .C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN

Comment: what about specifying the host/port manually instead of going through tnsnames?